# Twilio: Twiml.Gather() does not read keys

Tags: node.js, twilio

My response is as follows:

```
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   <Say>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:       press 1 for sales and go away now
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   </Say>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   <Say>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:       testeeee
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   </Say>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   <Gather action="http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/ivr" numDigits="1"/>
2012-02-13T09:04:38+00:00 app[web.1]: </Response>
```

But it seems that the Gather is not working. It does not recognize when I hit a key. Why?

Comment: What kind of phone are you calling from?

Comment: @JohnSheehan calling to an iphone? does it matter?

Comment: Sometimes if you're calling to a VoIP line, the digits aren't recognized. Probably not the case here. In this case, can you try wrapping the `<Say>` verbs with the `<Gather>`? That way you can press a key while the text is being read. Or add `timeout="20"` to your `<Gather>` to give yourself more time to enter something.

Answer (score 1):

Add another Say such as:

`<Say>This is after the Gather</Say>`

after the Gather.  Then if pressing your phone digits is really not getting recognized, the 5 second default timeout will be surpassed and then Twilio will fall through to the Say that you just added and you will hear that.  There is a chance that the Gather is actually POSTing to the action above but that url is not responding correctly.  This way you will be able to know where the problem is.